# Java Eclipse maven artifact not recognized

Tags: java

I have a maven multi-module project that is too large to post here but I am having some troubles importing dependencies, it seems like I am doing everything right but I am running into errors. Basically I import a dependency interface from another local module. In eclipse it works fine, I am not getting any errors. I import the interface and eclipse shows me a bunch of methods when I use it. I am getting an error message when running the app:

```
Field carServiceInterface in com.company.portal.controller.cars.ImportCarsController required a bean of type 'com.company.cars.service.CarServiceInterface' that could not be found.
```

It is weird because Eclipse is not complaining about not finding the package and the package helper in eclipse has all the methods when I use the interface:

```
@Autowired
CarServiceInterface carServiceInterface;
```

Do I need to do anything with maven on the command line? I tried update all maven modules in eclipse but that didnt work.

Additional Stack:

```
The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.company.cars.service.ImportCarsController' in your configuration.
```

Comment: have you tried a `mvn clean verify` command from the console?  this will download all dependencies (if not already downloaded)

Comment: Please add the full stack trace of the exception to your question.

Comment: It looks as though the problem is that you have not created a bean which implements that interface.

Comment: I updated my question with the additional error message

Comment: Eclipse does a great job of discovering dependencies using maven and from other projects in the same workspace. Maven, however, relies solely on the pom and your repository. Have these other modules been installed into your local repository or published to a remote repository?

Comment: The controller that implements the interface is using the @Component annotation as well but i discovered there is a NoBeanFoundException